# How can I post data to rails backend in Association has_and_belongs_to_many?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, ruby-on-rails-5, postman

As following
I create a association with two tables.

I added data at console is :

```
Deal.create(items: "items1", shop_id:1, customer_ids: "uuid")
```

and it was success.

But When I try to use postman to test

```
{"shop_id": 1, "items": "items2", "customer_ids": "uuid"}
```

and the new data customers is `null`

My controller:

```
def create
    @deal = Deal.new(deal_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @deal.save
        format.json { render :show, status: :created }
      else
        format.json { render json: @deal.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
def deal_params
    params.require(:deal).permit(:items, :shop_id, :customer_ids)
end
```

My routes:

```
post 'deals', to: 'deals#create'
```

The log is not occurred error.

What's the problem in my case?

**UPDATE**

I try the same data on my controller directly

```
@deal = Deal.new({"shop_id": 1, "items": "items2", "customer_ids": "uuid"})
```

and it success...

So I think the problem is on my deal_params function

I try the tutorial

```
params.require(:deal).permit(:items, :shop_id, :customer_ids => [])
```

But still no good

Comment: what was the route. did you called  a `create` operation somewhere?

Comment: @HaseebEqx I have added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you put `params.require(:deal)` before permitting others rails takes parameters under `:deal` only. so the input data must be

```
{"deal": {"shop_id": 1, "items": "items2", "customer_ids": "uuid"}}
```

or you may try to permit the other values directly like

```
params.permit(:items, :shop_id, :customer_ids => [])
```

Comment: Maybe I have wrong expression. In my case, the  `{"shop_id":1, items: "items2"}` have insert the database, but only `{customer_id: "uuid"}` not, So I don't understand why.

Comment: also set content type to application/json

Comment: Hell yah, It's successful but the the code in private should be `params.permit(:items, :shop_id, :customer_ids=>[])`

Answer (score 0):

```
{"deal" => {"shop_id" => 1, "items" => "items2", "customer_ids" => "uuid"}}
```

in your controller's private action is requiring `deal` so here you need to send data in to wrapper of `deal` as hash

```
params.require(:deal).permit(:items, :shop_id, :customer_ids)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
params.require(:deal).permit(:items, :shop_id, customer_ids: [])
```

what kind of relation your doing? has many trought? has many? has one?